# AS3/AIR/IOS recording a video on iphone and save it into native gallery directly WITHOUT native UI

Tags: ios, actionscript-3, video, air, camera

I'm developing an APP on iphone using as3,flash builder.

I'd like to know is this possible to record a video and save it into native gallery directly WITHOUT bump out the camera UI.

1.I've try taking photo and save it directly without showing CameraUI. And it works.

(use it--> cameraRoll.addBitmapData(_video))

*

2.but call the video should use this method -> deviceCameraApp.launch( MediaType.IMAGE );

this is the main reason that app launch the native camera UI I guess.

*

3.I've test an as3 [FLVRecorder library](https://code.google.com/p/flvrecorder/) build by Joris and work good in MAC.

And I'd like to move it to the APP.  But when I done the video record,I can't find my video on gallery maybe because of the video is saved into APP.
(like applicationStorageDirectory)

*

so here is my question:

1.is there other way to record and save video directly into gallery without Native camera UI in AS3?

/

2.if is not,could I done this with FLVRecorder library just change the path?

(I'm looking for something like /private/var/mobile/Media/DCIM)

Thanks for help!